# CloudFoundry app returning null not found error

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-foundry

I am completely new to Cloud development. I have created a Spring Project and deployed that into cloud foundry. On my local system, app runs fine without any issues. But when i go to Cloud Foundry and try to run my application via cf url, i am getting null Not found error. Please see the screenshot below. Could you please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: i am using cloud postgre as database

Comment: There is no screenshot linked.